# Is any additional attributes required to force the java type in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are using spring-integation (xml based configuration), In which we are performing below steps

1. Convert the payload (java-object) to json
2. Make the rest api call
3. Convert back to java-object

```xml
<int:object-to-json-transformer content-type="test.Request" input-channel="objectToJsonChannel" output-channel="apiChannel"/>
       <int-http:outbound-gateway id="apiChannel"
            request-channel="apiChannel"
            reply-channel="jsonToObjectChannel"
                        ....
            />
         <int:json-to-object-transformer type="test.Response" input-channel="jsonToObjectChannel" output-channel="responseChannel"/>
```

Above code works till spring-integration version 5.1. When I upgrade to 5.2. It starts to throw the exception as 
`org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [test.Request] to type [test.Response]`.

I have noticed that `object-to-json-transformer` add class type on the header with key `json__TypeId__`. Then it uses that class type for `json-to-object-transformer`.

But it is expected that type attribute mentioned on `json-to-object-transformer` should be used if mentioned.

Please suggest on fixing this issue or Is it really bug on spring integration (5.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to add a `<header-filter header-names="json_*" />` before calling your REST service. The `<int:object-to-json-transformer>` populates `JsonHeaders` to let downstream to know what the real type of JSON we curry in the payload.

A `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` prefers those headers instead of static `type` option.
But since the `payload` is already a different representation than those request headers it does a wrong thing.

I would suggest an option on the `<int:json-to-object-transformer>` to make a preference, but that would not be fully logical. Since we have changed a payload, it would be better to change its respective headers. Otherwise we just lying to ourselves.

On the other hand a HTTP Outbound Gateway can take care for your to convert request into a JSON for network and back from JSON response to some POJO type.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound and its `expected-response-type`. As long as a `contentType` header is an `application/json`, you are good to avoid those `<int:object-to-json-transformer>` & `<int:json-to-object-transformer>`.